# How to create list from model's object properties?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model:

```
var Project = DS.Model.extend({
  title:                DS.attr('string'),
  description:          DS.attr('string'),
  full_description:     DS.attr('string'),
  category:             DS.attr('string')
});
```

and I try to create a list that contains only `category` properties of all project instances in a model. And I try to do this in the following way, as a property on a controller:

```
  projectTitles: Ember.computed('model', function() {
    var projects = this.get('model');
    return project.map((project) => {
      return project.category;
    });
  })
```

But it doesn't work and due to small experience I can't figure out why.

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `returns projects.map`, you forgot the `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the getters and setters in ember as a universal rule.
- Observe the correct properties

__

```
projectCategories: Ember.computed('model.@each.category', function() {
    return this.get('model').map(p => p.get('category'));
});
```

Comment: There's a shorthand `mapBy('category')`

Comment: @dwickern do you mean I can replace all of this above just by `mapBy('category')` and get the same results ?

Comment: @NikitaLuparev You can replace `this.get('model').map(p => p.get('category'))` with `this.get('model').mapBy('category')` (using [`Array.prototype.mapBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_mapBy)) . You can also replace the whole `projectCategories` definition with `projectCategories: Ember.computed.mapBy('model', 'category')` (using [`Ember.computed.mapBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_mapBy)).